# Will multiple Android apps all have the same Facebook keyhash?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

This might seem obvious but it doesn't quite make sense to me...

I am developing two Android apps in Eclipse. Both use the Facebook-Android-sdk.

Will the Facebook keyhash be identical for both apps?

Answer (score 1):

If both uses same facebook app, then you have to sign both of your apps with same keystore.

If you want to have two different apps on facebook for your two android app, then it is recommended to have different keyhash generated for both separately.

Comment: So for testing, each would require its own official Facebook application installed on the emulator/device?

Comment: Why? it doesn't need official Facebook installed. if it is installed they both will authenticate using that single app. (Keep in mind that having two official Facebook app in single device is impossible usually).